# Running Outlook.EXE as Current User in VBScript

Tags: vbscript, outlook.application

I'm asking this for a colleague, just to determine if it's possible.

He has a vbscript file that runs under the System account. Part of the script contains a call to open Outlook, as follows:

```
strCommand = WshShell.Run (Chr(34) & "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\Outlook.exe" & chr(34))
```

This runs outlook as expected, but what he wants is for only that call to run under the logged in user's account.

is this possible?

Thanks
Martin

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the [runas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runas) command.

Comment: That's what i thought initially, but then found you'd need the password, which is not going to be available. Thanks anyway.

Comment: That's true.  There is no way to run a program as another user without providing their credentials.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't, because you'll then need the password of the logged on user. Plus you'll need to find out what the logged on user's account is in the first place (although that is relatively easy).

Comment: That's what I'd found out, which was why I'd asked the question seeing as the runas was not an option.